# SSRS: Tablix adding dummy rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I see that the, Tablix adding dummy rows.

[image: Dummy Values]

Where as, the definition has only one row which displays values OK, NOK and INVALID from dataset.

[image: Definition of Table]

I've executed the Stored Procedure, and see that the values are returning properly.

Please help me in understanding what am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In design mode you have one row Detail shown *which will repeat* when the report runs for every row returned by your dataset. So if your data has eight rows, you will get eight Detail rows showing the data in each of the eight rows of your dataset.

So the tablix won't be returning dummy rows, it will be simply showing the rows of the dataset. Now you have the word "Total" there, so I assume you want to see some sort of aggregate total and not show the detail rows.

There are two ways you can do this - in the tablix or in the dataset.

**In the Tablix**

In the table footer of your tablix, use an aggregation expression in the cells to get the total you need, for example:

```
=Count(Fields!OK.Value)
```

Delete the Detail row from your tablix so you only see the totals in the footer.

**In the dataset**

This may not be an option given you are using a stored procedure but you can aggregate in your SQL:

```
SELECT Count(OK) AS OK, Count(NOK) AS NOK, Count(Invalid) AS Invalid
FROM MyTable
```

This will give one row of totals that you can then display in your Detail row.